# links to my posts point to chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com instead of chemistry.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug

I have a question about my Chemistry Stack Exchange post: [Is there a terminology contradiction about whether the conjugate of a strong acid is a "weak base"?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92294/is-there-a-terminology-contradiction-about-whether-the-conjugate-of-a-strong-aci)

When I fill out the form to post a new question on chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com, it shows me the links to questions I have posted on chemistry.stackexchange.com, however the links are broken because the links point to chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com instead of chemistry.stackexchange.com.

Here is a screen shot -- the form shows me a list of my questions, and I'm hovering over the second question, so the URL appears in the status bar at the bottom.  (And if I click that link it gives 404.)

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Just to let you know: this is not within our control as site moderators, but since it is tagged with [meta-tag:bug], it will hopefully be looked into by the developer team soon. So, don't worry if there is no immediate response.